# Debugging test code

Tags: python, debugging

I wrote this just to test the "Property" function. However, I am getting a bug in the get_name function. I'd appreciate any help.

```
#The Property Critter
#Using New Classes vs Old Classes:

class Critter (object):
    def __init__ (self, name):
        print "A new critter has been born."
        self.__name = name

    def get_name (self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name (self, new_name):
        if new_name == "":
            print "The name can't be blank. Ass."
        else:
            self.__name = new_name
            print "Namt change successful."

name = property (get_name, set_name)

crit = Critter ("Pooch Dog")
print crit.name
crit.name = "Mad Dog"
print crit.name
```

Comment: could you please post your code here and not on another website

Comment: Can't see the problem... Maybe `name = property (get_name, set_name)` is lacking indentation or the site you pasted the code changed it?

Comment: @mu Seems too obvious to me... `get_name` and `set_name` aren't in the scope.

Comment: Sorry about not posting the code here. The indents get messed up whenever I try to post code straight to here. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @Louis93: don't use tabs, they are the enemy and SO can't handle them :/ If you text editor is any good it has a option to convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: @Jochen, code with tabs works fine (I frequently run code from here through `Lindent` to correct horrible indenting, and `Lindent` will output with tabs) -- BUT the four spaces in front of every line of code must be perfect. Because tabs _look_ like spaces, that's where things often go wrong. But prepending four spaces to all lines with `vim` or the `{}` editor function works well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indent your `name = property (get_name, set_name)` so that it is part of your Critter class:

```
class Critter (object):
    def __init__ (self, name):
        print "A new critter has been born."
        self.__name = name

    def get_name (self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name (self, new_name):
        if new_name == "":
            print "The name can't be blank. Ass."
        else:
            self.__name = new_name
            print "Namt change successful."

    name = property (get_name, set_name)

crit = Critter ("Pooch Dog")
print crit.name
crit.name = "Mad Dog"
print crit.name
```